# Are dishwasher overfill protection floats adjustable?

Tags: leak, appliances, dishwasher

Dishwasher leaks. It is practically level but slopes 1 degree toward the door. Owner's manual labels overfill protection float in the diagram but does not mention how to use it. Are these floats adjustable? If so, is it possible to use it to regulate water level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The float is likely not adjustable.  However, the diswasher has leveling feet and an excellent first step is to use them. Then clean the float area and all the folds and cracks of the rubber door seal.

Answer (score 0):

The float is normally a fixed height. I would recommend that you carefully disassemble and inspect/clean the float assembly. If debris or mineral deposits are hindering free movement of the float it could be allowing the dishwasher to overfill, causing a leak at the lower door seal. Also inspect the condition of the door seal itself, crusty and damaged door seals are a common cause of small leaks.

If you cant adjust the front to level it, try some shims under the front frame or feet to get it level.

Occasionally run an empty cycle with a cup of white vinegar to help remove mineral deposits and keep your dishwasher clean.